# How to access to the global variable from an anonymous function in the Go?

Tags: go

I have a code:

```
var test string

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        test = "index"
    })

    fmt.Println(test)

    if error := http.ListenAndServe(":9001", nil); error != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error!", error)
    }
}
```

How to change the value of the **test** variable in the anonymous function? I will be thankful!

Comment: Your HTTP handler func does change it, but you print the value before the HTTP server is even started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP handler *does* change your global variable; however you don't protect access to the global variable and thus have a race condition. That is to say `fmt.Println(test)` runs before your `http.HandleFunc`.

I'm assuming this is a toy example: If you want to change your code to wait for the value to be changed / wait for an HTTP hit, before terminating, then you could do this:

```
var test string
var doneCh = make(chan bool, 1)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        test = "index"
        select {
        case doneCh <- true:
        default:
        }
    })

    go func() {
        <-doneCh
        fmt.Println(test)
    }()

    if error := http.ListenAndServe(":9001", nil); error != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error!", error)
    }
}
```

This uses a channel to guard the state of `test`. In real code it would be more likely to use [`sync.Once`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once) or [`sync.Mutex`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex). Also, I should mention (and I hope you already realize) mutating global state is always something to be avoided when possible.